# SQL: How to get result where if matching ID, then select which to keep based on another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Maybe there's a really easy solution but I dont see it because I been doing this all day and my brain is fried

How do I clean out the dupes from the source table to the Goal table?
[image]

Comment: These are not really duplicates.  The values are different in the rows.

Comment: correct, I was struggling with how to articulate it

Comment: Graphical representation of various joins, http://stevestedman.com/wp-content/uploads/VennDiagram1.pdf    This should help along with the other answers posted.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the suggestions and report back

Comment: Thanks everybody for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select id, version, otherinfo
from
(
select id, version, otherinfo, 
       row_number() over (partition by id order by version desc) as rownum
from source ) s
where rownum = 1;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3c74b/3)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT * 
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY [Version] DESC) rn
FROM TableName
)
DELETE FROM X
WHERE rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

Do you want aggregation?

```
select id, max(version) as version
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: then cant get the otherinfo field

Answer (score 0):

this work in sql server, i name the table Dupes
For show data w/o dupes

```
SELECT        id, version, otherinfo
FROM            Dupes AS t1
WHERE        (version =
(SELECT        MAX(version) AS LastVersion
FROM            Dupes AS t2
WHERE        (id = t1.id)))
```

This for delete dupes

```
DELETE FROM Dupes
WHERE        (version <
(SELECT        MAX(version) AS LastVersion
FROM            Dupes AS t2
WHERE        (id = Dupes.id)))
```